# mysql too many connection problems

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database-connection

I'm currently working on maintenance of an old project. I have "too many connection problem".I know the error is on the code(not closing connections), but to investigate each frame required more time. "**I'm looking for a way to close all connections that are sleep or idle for a long time or if the connection pool is maximum**".

Answer (score 2):

Increase your connections by using `set global max connections`.

Below:

```
show variables like "max_connections";

set global max_connections = 200;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(connection.State==ConnectionState.Open)
{
 connection.Close();
}
```

Try with this.!